# ROS Answers SE migration: rqt compass

Tags: rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I want to make a compass plugin in rqt, but I'm finding it quite hard since it's not a widget for compass in qtCreator.
Have anyone done this before or have any suggestions on how to do it/where to begin?
I'm using python if that's relevant.

I've tried to implement this one from the link below, but I get errors on qwt that I can't figure out.  https://github.com/SyllogismRXS/syllo-ros/tree/master/catkin_ws/src/rqt_compass

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257729/rqt-compass/) by [fonstein](https://answers.ros.org/users/28963/fonstein/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could try [QCompass](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompass.html). It looks like available since Qt5.1 only so you may want to try it on [ROS Kinetic](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#kinetic-kame-may-2016-may-2021) or higher for better Qt5 support.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fonstein](https://answers.ros.org/users/28963/fonstein/) on 2017-04-27**:
Do you have any experience with QCompass? I've only made plugins based on components found in QtCreator and QCompass isn't there.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-04-27**:
I haven't used it. AFAI remember you can use components that don't show up on `QtCreator`. Just do it :)